# How can I print a number larger than 32 bits in mips assembly?

Tags: assembly, printing, overflow, mips, multiplication

In my mips assembly code, I used the multi instruction to multiply 2 large numbers since the result could not fit in one register.  This means that the number is saved in the hi and lo special registers.  My problem is how do I print the result of the multiplication.  I can access hi and lo and put them in other registers (i.e. $t0, $t1), but I do not know of a way to combine the two numbers in order to print the result.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer kept deliberately high-level, since I'm pretty sure no one prints numbers in mips assembly unless they're doing it for a homework assignment.)

If you don't mind getting it in hex, it's no problem; just print one word in hex, and then the next one.  Don't forget to include the leading zeroes on the second word!  (Actually I think spim, which I presume you're using, can only print in base 10, so even this might be a bit of a chore).

If you want it in base 10, this problem quickly heads into the category I would call 'pain-in-the-ass'.  In 'real life', I wouldn't bother; do the printing in C, some compiler guy somewhere solved all these problems for you.  For homework, write yourself a function that divides the input by 10 repeatedly and you'll eventually end up with the digits to print out.  If mips doesn't have a 64-bit divide instruction (couldn't tell you off the top of my head) this is going to be a pretty fun problem for you to solve.

Answer (score -1):

the solution to print the number is really dividing the number repeatedly by 10 and get the rest of division and store in a string and then read it upside down. But the only challenge is divide the 64-bit number if the mips32 only have 32-bits division. I find a way in this page:

https://www.codeproject.com/questions/714114/how-to-print-bit-in